# How to declare an external structure in C

Tags: c, struct, global-variables, declaration, extern

I have already implement an external `int` in my .h file, with
`extern int GLOBAL_RETURNVAL;`.

I would like to know how to declare an external structure in the same way (to contain both this `int` and also a `char *`).

Trying

```
extern struct S_GLOBAL 
{
    int GLOBAL_RETURNVAL;
    char *PWD;
};
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would ike to implement a global structure where i can implement an int and a char * to be able tohave an access to these 2 parameters in all my files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this declaration

```
extern int GLOBAL_RETURNVAL;
```

there is declared an object of the type `int`. An object can have external linkage.

In this (incorrect) declaration

```
extern struct S_GLOBAL  { int GLOBAL_RETURNVAL char *PWD };
```

you are trying to declare the type specifier `struct S_GLOBAL`. Structure type specifiers are not allowed to be declared with storage class specifiers (like `extern`) except using the storage class specifier `typedef`.

If you will write for example

```
struct S_GLOBAL  { int GLOBAL_RETURNVAL; char *PWD; };
```

then the data member `int GLOBAL,_RETURNVAL` of the structure declaration is not the same as the object

```
extern int GLOBAL_RETURNVAL;
```

It seems you want to declare in a header an object of the structure type as for example

```
extern struct S_GLOBAL S_GLOBAL;
```

and in some module to initialize its data members like for example

```
struct S_GLOBAL S_GLOBAL = { .GLOBAL_RETURNVAL = GLOBAL,_RETURNVAL, .PWD = NULL };
```

Or the structure could be declared like

```
struct S_GLOBAL  { int *GLOBAL_RETURNVAL; char *PWD; };
```

and an object of the structure type could be initialized like

```
struct S_GLOBAL S_GLOBAL = { .GLOBAL_RETURNVAL = &GLOBAL,_RETURNVAL, .PWD = NULL };
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you ! I forget to initialize it on my "main file" ;) and the declaration process works perfectly well

Comment: Re “Type specifiers are not allowed to be declared with storage class specifiers (like `extern`) except using the storage class specifier `typedef`”: This is not a rule in the C standard. Nor would it be a workable rule; ordinary declarations like `extern int x;` include both a storage class specifier (`extern`) and a type specifier (`int`). if there is no declarator, then a storage class specifier other than `typedef` is superfluous, but it is not disallowed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You showed an object declaration not a type specifier declaration.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The C standard does not distinguish anything as a “type specifier declaration.” A struct-or-union specifier with a struct-declaration-list declares a type (C 2018 6.7.2.1 8 and 6.7.2.3 6), and a struct-or-union specifier with a tag declares the tag (with certain constraints, 6.7.2.3 6, 7, and 8). Regardless, there is no rule in the C standard against having a storage class specifier other than `typedef` with a type specifier, with or without a declarator.

Comment: @EricPostpischil One more you showed a declaration of an object not a declaration of a structure type specifier. The storage class specifier extern is relative to the declared object.  It may not be used in a structure declaration. It may be used only in an object or a function declaration.

Comment: `extern struct S_GLOBAL  { int GLOBAL_RETURNVAL; char *PWD; };` is a valid declaration in the C standard. There is no rule against using a storage class specifier other than `typedef` with a type specifier, regardless of the form of declaration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Such a declaration is undefined in the C Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Where does the C standard say that? It is allowed by the grammar in C 2018 6.7, and none of the subclauses to that prohibit it or say it is not defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The grammar is not the same as the semantic. The behavior of such a declaration is undefined in C. There is nowhere in the C Standard is said what it means. The semantic of the storage class specifier extern or static is defined only for objects and functions.

Comment: `extern struct S_GLOBAL  { int GLOBAL_RETURNVAL; char *PWD; };` is given meaning by 6.7.2.1 8, 6.7.2.3 6, and other paragraphs in 6.7 (it declares a structure and a tag), so its behavior is defined. Nothing in 6.7 prohibits it, takes away that meaning, or says it is undefined. GCC, Clang, and MSVC accept it. You asserted “Structure type specifiers are not allowed to be declared with storage class specifiers (like `extern`) except using the storage class specifier `typedef`.” There is no such rule; no rule in the C standard says that is not allowed. If you believe otherwise, show us the rule.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If I am not mistaken then neither 6.7.2.1 8 nor 6.7.2.3 6 says about storage class specifiers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yes, they do not say anything about it. That is fine. Being silent about something is not a prohibition and does not undo any definition. The storage class specifier is superfluous but not disallowed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The semantic is not defined. It means that the behavior is undefined.